# How to change data types "object" in Pandas dataframe after importing a CSV?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have imported a CSV file as a Pandas dataframe. When I run `df.dtypes` I get most columns as "object", which is useless for taking into Bokeh for charts.

1. I need to change a column as `int`, another column as `date`, and the rest as strings.
2. I see the data types only once I import it.  Would you recommend changing it during import (how?), or after import?

Answer (score 4):

I think for datetime need `parse_dates` parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

If you have `int` column and dont get `int64` `dtype`, I think there are some `strings` maybe `empty strings`, because `read_csv` aoutomatically cast `dtypes`.

Then need convert bad data to `NaN` by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) - but get `float` column because `NaN` has `float` type. So need replace `NaN` to some int (e.g. `0`) and then cast to `int`:

```
df['col_int'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col_int'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""a;b;c;d
A;2015-01-01;3;e
S;2015-01-03;4;r
D;2015-01-05;5r;t"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", parse_dates=[1])
print (df)
   a          b   c  d
0  A 2015-01-01   3  e
1  S 2015-01-03   4  r
2  D 2015-01-05  5r  t

print (df.dtypes)
a            object
b    datetime64[ns]
c            object
d            object
dtype: object

df['c'] = pd.to_numeric(df['c'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   a          b  c  d
0  A 2015-01-01  3  e
1  S 2015-01-03  4  r
2  D 2015-01-05  0  t

print (df.dtypes)
a            object
b    datetime64[ns]
c             int32
d            object
dtype: object
```

---

For change `dtypes` need `dtype` parameter:

```
temp=u"""a;b;c;d
A;10;3;e
S;2;4;r
D;6;1;t"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", dtype={'b':str, 'c':float})
print (df)
   a   b    c  d
0  A  10  3.0  e
1  S   2  4.0  r
2  D   6  1.0  t

print (df.dtypes)
a     object
b     object
c    float64
d     object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

During reading a csv file:

Use dtype or converters attribute in read_csv in pandas

`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',dtypes = {'a':float64,'b':int32},headers=None)`

Here,automatically the types will be read as the datatype you specified.

After having read the csv file:

Use astype function to change the column types.

Check this code.
Consider you have two columns

`df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].astype(float)`

The advantage of this is you change type of multiple columns at once.

Answer (score 0):

**Use one-hot encoding.**

here datatype converts from object to category and then it converts to int64.
But this method is used in categorical data.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
dataframe = pd.read_csv('path//filename.csv')
dataframe ["attribute"] = dataframe ["attribute"].astype('category')
dataframe ["attribute_cat"] = dataframe ["attribute"].cat.codes
```